# R: the correlation is strong, but the graphic is very noisy

Tags: r, visualization, correlation

I have the following piece of code:

```
ggplot(df[(df$UkrBall100 >=100)&(df$mathBall100 >= 100)], aes(x=UkrBall100 ,y = mathBall100), xlim = c(100,200), ylim = c(100,200)) + 
    geom_point() + geom_abline() +labs(
    title = "Взаимосвязь между результатом по математике и результатом по украинскому"
  )
print(cor(select(df[(df$UkrBall100 >=100)&(df$mathBall100 >= 100)], c(UkrBall100, mathBall100))))
```

And the problem is that correlation between these two variables is rather high:

```
            UkrBall100 mathBall100
UkrBall100   1.0000000   0.7238777
mathBall100  0.7238777   1.0000000
```

But the graph is very noisy and seems not to show any correlation.
[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering out variables from two different dataframes.based on different values and plotting the ggplot.
The correlation seems to be high as you have specifically chosen the values greater than 100.

What about the plot if you don't filter the values and choose all the values of the 2 variables?